# How to pass an argument to a stateful widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following stateful widget

```
class MyDiaryScreen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final AnimationController animationController;
  MyDiaryScreen2({Key key, this.animationController}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyDiaryScreen2State createState() => _MyDiaryScreen2State();
  int index;
}

class _MyDiaryScreen2State extends State<MyDiaryScreen2>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> topBarAnimation;

  List<Widget> listViews = List<Widget>();
  var scrollController = ScrollController();
  double topBarOpacity = 1.0;
}
```

I have called this Widget from another Widget as

```
onTap: () {MyDiaryScreen2();},
```

But I want to pass a parameter MealsView.index of type int to MyDiaryScreen2 like this

```
onTap: () {MyDiaryScreen2(MealsView.index);},
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just pass it as a plain argument when initializing `MyDiaryScreen2`:

```
onTap: () => MyDiaryScreen2(
  animationController: <controller>,
  index: MealsView.index,
)
```

Of course, do not forget to adjust `MyDiaryScreen2` to accept `index` in the constructor.

```
class MyDiaryScreen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final AnimationController animationController;
  final int index;

  MyDiaryScreen2({Key key, this.animationController, this.index}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyDiaryScreen2State createState() => _MyDiaryScreen2State();
}
```